# How to Add Business Logic in CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Business Logic Is :-

1. If items are even, then display them 2 in each row.
2. If items are odd, display the first one to span the full row, and show the remaining spanning 2 in each row.

Comment: What you want to do is a custom collectionView layout, there is a really good tutorial on RayWenderlich website:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Check items.count in `sizeForItemAt` method and return `collectionView.bounds.width` if it is first row and items count is odd. Else return `collectionView.bounds.width / 2`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if items.count % 2 == 1 && indexPath == IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0) {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 50)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.width / 2) - 10, height: 50)
    }
}
```

**Odd**

[image]

**Even**

[image]